# How to add a new field in an existing report in SSRS?The added field shows the SQL query not the return value

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am using Microsoft SQL Report Builder 2008 to customise SSRS report generated from Epicor ERP system. I download SSRS reporting style, customise it report builder and then upload it in Epicor to see the changes that I have made in the report.

My SSRS report contains a Project Lead field, but it does not show the Project Lead name. So I am trying to find a way of showing the name here. The POHeader dataset in the report does not contain any Project Lead value, which is "PersonID". Therefore, I have written a subquery that returns the "Project_Lead" value from multiple dataset which is not within the current report, but I have linked that query with the report dataset so that when it matches the "PONum" value it will return the "PersonID", which is the name of project lead.

However, the field shows the SELECT statement instead of the return value. The SQL query is correct and I have run it in the EPICOR system from where the report is generated. I am customising the report by adding this "PersonID" value in the Project Lead field.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

1.I have written a subquery that returns PersonID value from 3 database tables.

2. Then I have made connection between subquery that contains PersonID value with the POHeader dataset
3. The subquery and POHeader both contain PONum. So, when the PONum matches each other, the POHeader will return the PersonID value.
4. I have created a Textbox field in the report. In the expression field, I have included the SQL subquery that returns the PersonID value with the relation with POHeader dataset.
5. I have then save the SSRS report. And uploaded the reporting style in the Epicor system where I will generate a PDF report based on the SSRS modification that I have just made in the textbox field.

6.However, the textbox field shows the whole SQL query when I am trying to view it as a preview in the system

```
="SELECT
   [PlannerID].[JobHead_PersonID] as [JobHead_PersonID]
from  (select 
    [POHeader].[PONum] as [POHeader_PONum],
    [JobHead].[PersonID] as [JobHead_PersonID],
    [JobHead].[JobNum] as [JobHead_JobNum]
from Erp.POHeader as POHeader
inner join Erp.PODetail as PODetail on 
    POHeader.Company = PODetail.Company
    and POHeader.PONum = PODetail.PONUM
inner join Erp.PORel as PORel on 
    PODetail.Company = PORel.Company
    and PODetail.PONUM = PORel.PONum
    and PODetail.POLine = PORel.POLine
inner join Erp.JobHead as JobHead on 
    PORel.Company = JobHead.Company
    and PORel.JobNum = JobHead.JobNum)  as PlannerID
 right outer join Erp.POHeader as POHeader1 on 
    POHeader1.PONum = PlannerID.POHeader_PONum 
    POHeader.Company = PODetail.Company
    and POHeader.PONum = PODetail.PONUM
inner join Erp.PORel as PORel on 
    PODetail.Company = PORel.Company
    and PODetail.PONUM = PORel.PONum
    and PODetail.POLine = PORel.POLine
inner join Erp.JobHead as JobHead on 
    PORel.Company = JobHead.Company
    and PORel.JobNum = JobHead.JobNum)  as PlannerID
right outer join Erp.POHeader as POHeader1 on 
    POHeader1.PONum = PlannerID.POHeader_PONum"
```

The expected result will be a name of the project Lead instead I am getting the above query in that particular field of the report.

So this is my whole SQL after adding the subquery within it. The subquery included in the very last part of the code. If you can have a look and suggest whether I have made some mistakes while making the relationships among different tables, that would be a great help for me. The first line of the SQL SELECT statement, I have called the personID from the subquery.

```
 ="SELECT
     PlannerID.T5.PersonID, T3.TranType, T3.ProjectID, T3.JobNum, 
 T3.AssemblySeq, T3.JobSeq,  T1.RptLanguageID,
      T1.CommentText,
      T1.Company,
      T1.FOB,
      T1.FreightPP,         T1.EntryPerson,         T1.DueDate,         
T1.OrderDate,
      T1.PONum,
      T1.PrintAs,
      T1.ShipToConName,
      T1.ShipViaCode,
      T1.Calc_AccountRef,
      T1.Calc_BillToAddrList,
      T1.Calc_Buyer,
      T1.Calc_CurDesc,
      T1.Calc_CurSymb,
      CAST(T1.Calc_ExistingDropShipReleases AS nvarchar) AS 
Calc_ExistingDropShipReleases,
      T1.Calc_FOBDesc,
      CAST(T1.Calc_MultiShiptoAddresses AS nvarchar) AS 
Calc_MultiShiptoAddresses,
      T1.Calc_PurTerms,
      T1.Calc_ShipToAddrList,
      T1.Calc_ShipVia,
      T1.Calc_VendorContact,
      T1.Calc_VendPhone,
      T1.Calc_VendFax,
      T1.Calc_EMail,
      T1.BuyerID_EMailAddress,
      T1.Vendor_EMailAddress,
      T1.Vendor_FaxNum,
      T1.VendorCnt_EmailAddress,
      T1.Calc_TotDocMiscAmt,
      T1.VendorCnt_FaxNum,
      T1.InPrice,
      T1.DocTotalMisc,
      T1.DocTotalTax,
      T2.CommentText AS PODetail_CommentText,
      T2.Company AS PODetail_Company,
      T2.DocUnitCost,
      T2.MfgPartNum,
      T2.MfgPartOpts,
      T2.PartNum,
      T2.POLine,
      T2.PONUM AS PODetail_PONum,
      T2.PUM,
      T2.RevisionNum,
      T2.SubPartNum,
      T2.SubPartOpts,
      T2.SubPartType,
      T2.Taxable,
      T2.VendorPartOpts,
      T2.VenPartNum,
      T2.Calc_CostPer,
      T2.Calc_DtLineDesc,
      T2.Calc_ExtCost,
      T2.Calc_UOMDescription,
      T2.Calc_MfgID,
      T2.Calc_InTaxAmt,
      T2.DocExtCost,
      T4.Calc_AccountRef AS RptLiteralsCalc_AccountRef,
      T4.RptLiteralsLFax,
      T4.FreightPP AS RptLiteralsFreightPP,
      T4.RptLiteralsLAuthBy,
      T4.RptLiteralsLChangeOrder,
      T4.RptLiteralsLClosed,
      T4.RptLiteralsLDueDt,
      T4.RptLiteralsLExtPrice,
      T4.RptLiteralsLFOB,
      T4.RptLiteralsLHdng,
      T4.RptLiteralsLJobNum,
      T4.RptLiteralsLLine,
      T4.RptLiteralsLLineChargeSubtotal,
      T4.RptLiteralsLMfgPartNumber,
      T4.RptLiteralsLMiscChargeSubtotal,
      T4.RptLiteralsLMslshS,
      T4.RptLiteralsLOrderDate,
      T4.RptLiteralsLOrderQty,
      T4.RptLiteralsLOurPartNumber,
      T4.RptLiteralsLPg,
      T4.RptLiteralsLPhone,
      T4.RptLiteralsLPONum,
      T4.RptLiteralsLPrtRvDes,
      T4.RptLiteralsLQty,
      T4.RptLiteralsLResalNo,
      T4.RptLiteralsLRevised,
      T4.RptLiteralsLSeeBelow,
      T4.RptLiteralsLSeq,
      T4.RptLiteralsLShipTo,
      T4.RptLiteralsLShipVia,
      T4.RptLiteralsLShRelReq,
      T4.RptLiteralsLSubstitute,
      T4.RptLiteralsLSubstitutedFor,
      T4.RptLiteralsLSupplierPartNumber,
      T4.RptLiteralsLTax,
      T4.RptLiteralsLTerms,
      T4.RptLiteralsLTotal,
      T4.RptLiteralsLUnitPric,
      T4.RptLiteralsLVend,
      T4.RptLiteralsLLnMsChrg,
      T4.RptLiteralsLDesc,
      T4.PONum AS RptLiteralsPONum,
      T4.RptLiteralsLAmt,
      T4.RptLiteralsLTaxSubtotal,
      T4.RptLiteralsLYes,
      T4.RptLiteralsLNo,
      T4.RptLiteralsLBuyer
     , T1.[CurrencyCode], T1.[DocTotalCharges], T1.[DocTotalDedTax], T1. 
[DocTotalOrder], T1.[DocTotalSATax], T1.[DocTotalWhTax], T1. 
[POTaxReadyToProcess], T1.[PromiseDate], T1.[TotalCharges], T1. 
[TotalDedTax], T1.[TotalMiscCharges], T1.[TotalOrder], T1.[TotalSATax], 
T1. 
 [TotalTax], T1.[TotalWhTax], T1.[Character01], T1.[Character02], T1. 
[Character03], T1.[Character04], T1.[Character05], T1.[CheckBox01], T1. 
[CheckBox02], T1.[CheckBox03], T1.[CheckBox04], T1.[CheckBox05], T1. 
[Date01], 
T1.[Date02], T1.[Date03], T1.[Date04], T1.[Date05], T1.[Number01], T1. 
[Number02], T1.[Number03], T1.[Number04], T1.[Number05], T1.[ShortChar01], 
T1.[ShortChar02], T1.[ShortChar03], T1.[ShortChar04], T1.[ShortChar05], 
T1. 
[Calc_CarrierDesc], T1.[Calc_CarrierSCAC], T1.[Calc_INBillToAddrList], T1. 
[Calc_INShipToAddrList], T1.[Calc_INTotalWords], T1. 
[Calc_PlantAddressInRelease], T1.[Calc_RPTUSERID], T1.[Calc_VendorID], T1. 
[BuyerID_Name], T1.[VendorCnt_Name], T1.[VendorCnt_PhoneNum], T2. 
[CommodityCode], T2.[DocMiscCost], T2.[ExtCost], T2.[GroupSeq], T2. 
[InUnitCost], T2.[MiscCost], T2.[NoTaxRecalc], T2.[PCLinkRemoved], T2. 
[Per], 
T2.[Rpt1TotalDedTax], T2.[Rpt1TotalSATax], T2.[Rpt1TotalTax], T2. 
[Rpt2TotalDedTax], T2.[Rpt2TotalSATax], T2.[Rpt2TotalTax], T2. 
[Rpt3TotalDedTax], T2.[Rpt3TotalSATax], T2.[Rpt3TotalTax], T2.[TaxCatID], 
T2.[UOM], T2.[Date06], T2.[Date07], T2.[Number11], T2.[ShortChar06], T2. 
[ShortChar07], T2.[Calc_DispUnitCost], T2.[Calc_LastLin], T2.[Calc_OurUM], 
T2.[Calc_OurUM_UOMSymbol], T2.[Calc_PartUDChr1], T2.[Calc_PartUDChr2], T2. 
[Calc_PartUDChr3], T2.[Calc_PartUDChr4], T2.[Calc_PartUDDat1], T2. 
[Calc_PartUDDat2], T2.[Calc_PartUDDat3], T2.[Calc_PartUDDat4], T2. 
[Calc_PartUDDec1], T2.[Calc_PartUDDec2], T2.[Calc_PartUDDec3], T2. 
[Calc_PartUDDec4], T2.[Calc_PartUDInt1], T2.[Calc_PartUDInt2], T2. 
[Calc_UnitCost], T2.[ContractQtyUOM_UOMSymbol], T2.[PUM_UOMSymbol], T4. 
[DecimalsGeneral] as RptLabelsDecimalsGeneral, T4.[DecimalsPrice] as 
RptLabelsDecimalsPrice, T4.[DecimalsCost] as RptLabelsDecimalsCost, T4. 
[GlbDecimalsGeneral] as RptLabelsGlbDecimalsGeneral, T4.[GlbDecimalsPrice] 
as RptLabelsGlbDecimalsPrice, T4.[GlbDecimalsCost] as 
RptLabelsGlbDecimalsCost, T4.[RptLiteralsPage], T4.[RptLiteralsTime], T4. 
[RptLiteralsUser], T4.[RptLiteralsDate], T4.[RptLiteralsLAsm], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLCarrier], T4.[RptLiteralsLCarrierSCAC], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLChange], T4.[RptLiteralsLClosedCAP], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLFrtPaid], 
T4.[RptLiteralsLINCommodityCode], T4.[RptLiteralsLINDescription], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLINFooterDate], T4.[RptLiteralsLINFooterDesignation], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLINFooterName], T4.[RptLiteralsLINFooterSignature], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLINPartNumber], T4.[RptLiteralsLINRatePercent], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLINTotal], T4.[RptLiteralsLOrder], T4.[RptLiteralsLOrMsChrg], 
 T4.[RptLiteralsLOurPart], T4.[RptLiteralsLPercent], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLslshC], T4.[RptLiteralsLslshM], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLTaxableAmount], T4.[RptLiteralsLTaxAmount], T4. 
[RptLiteralsLTaxes], T4.[ActTypeCode] as RptLabelsActTypeCode, T4. 
[APBOECheck] as RptLabelsAPBOECheck, T4.[CalendarID] as 
RptLabelsCalendarID, T4.[ChiefAcctName] as RptLabelsChiefAcctName, T4. 
[Company] as RptLabelsCompany, T4.[COSequenceCert] as 
RptLabelsCOSequenceCert, T4.[CountryNum] as RptLabelsCountryNum, T4. 
[CurrentFiscalYear] as RptLabelsCurrentFiscalYear, T4.[DeepCopy] as 
RptLabelsDeepCopy, T4.[DeepCopyDupOrRevEst] as 
RptLabelsDeepCopyDupOrRevEst, T4.[EDICode] as RptLabelsEDICode, T4. 
[EmpPhotoPath] as RptLabelsEmpPhotoPath, T4.[EpicorAccountNum] as 
RptLabelsEpicorAccountNum, T4.[EschedFileSet] as RptLabelsEschedFileSet, 
T4.[ExternalID] as RptLabelsExternalID, T4.[FaxNum] as RptLabelsFaxNum, 
T4.[FEIN] as RptLabelsFEIN, T4.[FiscalCalendarID] as 
RptLabelsFiscalCalendarID, T4.[FRxDSN] as RptLabelsFRxDSN, T4. 
[FRxPassWord] as RptLabelsFRxPassWord, T4.[FrxUserid] as 
RptLabelsFrxUserid, T4.[LegalName] as RptLabelsLegalName, T4.[LogoFile] as 
RptLabelsLogoFile, T4.[ManagerName] as RptLabelsManagerName, T4.[MapURL] 
as RptLabelsMapURL, T4.[MXMunicipio] as RptLabelsMXMunicipio, T4.[Number] 
as RptLabelsNumber, T4.[OrgRegCode] as RptLabelsOrgRegCode, T4.[PhoneNum] 
as RptLabelsPhoneNum, T4.[SendToFSA] as RptLabelsSendToFSA, T4. 
[StateTaxID] as RptLabelsStateTaxID, T4.[TaxRegionCode] as 
RptLabelsTaxRegionCode, T4.[TaxRegReason] as RptLabelsTaxRegReason, T4. 
[WIApplication] as RptLabelsWIApplication, T4.[WIAutoCreateJob] as 
RptLabelsWIAutoCreateJob, T4.[WIGetDetails] as RptLabelsWIGetDetails, T4. 
[WIRelease] as RptLabelsWIRelease, T4.[WISchedule] as RptLabelsWISchedule, 
T4.[WIShippingCosts] as RptLabelsWIShippingCosts, T4.[Calc_AddressList] as 
RptLabelsCalc_AddressList, T4.[Calc_INAddressList] as 
RptLabelsCalc_INAddressList, T4.[Calc_PrintCompanyName] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PrintCompanyName, T4.[CommentText] as RptLabelsCommentText, 
T4.[CurrencyCode] as RptLabelsCurrencyCode, T4.[DocTotalCharges] as 
RptLabelsDocTotalCharges, T4.[DocTotalDedTax] as RptLabelsDocTotalDedTax, 
T4.[DocTotalMisc] as RptLabelsDocTotalMisc, T4.[DocTotalOrder] as 
RptLabelsDocTotalOrder, T4.[DocTotalSATax] as RptLabelsDocTotalSATax, T4. 
[DocTotalTax] as RptLabelsDocTotalTax, T4.[DocTotalWhTax] as 
RptLabelsDocTotalWhTax, T4.[DueDate] as RptLabelsDueDate, T4.[EntryPerson] 
as RptLabelsEntryPerson, T4.[FOB] as RptLabelsFOB, T4.[FreightPP] as 
RptLabelsFreightPP, T4.[InPrice] as RptLabelsInPrice, T4.[OrderDate] as 
RptLabelsOrderDate, T4.[PONum] as RptLabelsPONum, T4.[POTaxReadyToProcess] 
as RptLabelsPOTaxReadyToProcess, T4.[PrintAs] as RptLabelsPrintAs, T4. 
[PromiseDate] as RptLabelsPromiseDate, T4.[ShipToConName] as 
RptLabelsShipToConName, T4.[ShipViaCode] as RptLabelsShipViaCode, T4. 
[TotalCharges] as RptLabelsTotalCharges, T4.[TotalDedTax] as 
RptLabelsTotalDedTax, T4.[TotalMiscCharges] as RptLabelsTotalMiscCharges, 
T4.[TotalOrder] as RptLabelsTotalOrder, T4.[TotalSATax] as 
RptLabelsTotalSATax, T4.[TotalTax] as RptLabelsTotalTax, T4.[TotalWhTax] 
as RptLabelsTotalWhTax, T4.[Calc_AccountRef] as RptLabelsCalc_AccountRef, 
T4.[Calc_BillToAddrList] as RptLabelsCalc_BillToAddrList, T4.[Calc_Buyer] 
as RptLabelsCalc_Buyer, T4.[Calc_CarrierDesc] as 
RptLabelsCalc_CarrierDesc, T4.[Calc_CarrierSCAC] as 
RptLabelsCalc_CarrierSCAC, T4.[Calc_CurDesc] as RptLabelsCalc_CurDesc, T4. 
[Calc_CurSymb] as RptLabelsCalc_CurSymb, T4.[Calc_EMail] as 
RptLabelsCalc_EMail, T4.[Calc_ExistingDropShipReleases] as 
RptLabelsCalc_ExistingDropShipReleases, T4.[Calc_FOBDesc] as 
RptLabelsCalc_FOBDesc, T4.[Calc_INBillToAddrList] as 
RptLabelsCalc_INBillToAddrList, T4.[Calc_INShipToAddrList] as 
RptLabelsCalc_INShipToAddrList, T4.[Calc_INTotalWords] as 
RptLabelsCalc_INTotalWords, T4.[Calc_MultiShiptoAddresses] as 
RptLabelsCalc_MultiShiptoAddresses, T4.[Calc_PlantAddressInRelease] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PlantAddressInRelease, T4.[Calc_PurTerms] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PurTerms, T4.[Calc_RPTUSERID] as RptLabelsCalc_RPTUSERID, 
T4.[Calc_ShipToAddrList] as RptLabelsCalc_ShipToAddrList, T4. 
[Calc_ShipVia] as RptLabelsCalc_ShipVia, T4.[Calc_TotDocMiscAmt] as 
RptLabelsCalc_TotDocMiscAmt, T4.[Calc_VendFax] as RptLabelsCalc_VendFax, 
T4.[Calc_VendorContact] as RptLabelsCalc_VendorContact, T4.[Calc_VendorID] 
as RptLabelsCalc_VendorID, T4.[Calc_VendPhone] as RptLabelsCalc_VendPhone, 
T4. 
[EMailAddress] as RptLabelsEMailAddress, T4.[Name] as RptLabelsName, T4. 
[CommodityCode] as RptLabelsCommodityCode, T4.[DocExtCost] as 
RptLabelsDocExtCost, T4.[DocMiscCost] as RptLabelsDocMiscCost, T4. 
[DocUnitCost] as RptLabelsDocUnitCost, T4.[ExtCost] as RptLabelsExtCost, 
T4.[GroupSeq] as RptLabelsGroupSeq, T4.[InUnitCost] as 
RptLabelsInUnitCost, T4.[MfgPartNum] as RptLabelsMfgPartNum, T4. 
[MfgPartOpts] as RptLabelsMfgPartOpts, T4.[MiscCost] as RptLabelsMiscCost, 
T4.[NoTaxRecalc] as RptLabelsNoTaxRecalc, T4.[PartNum] as 
RptLabelsPartNum, T4.[PCLinkRemoved] as RptLabelsPCLinkRemoved, T4.[Per] 
as RptLabelsPer, T4.[POLine] as RptLabelsPOLine, T4.[PUM] as RptLabelsPUM, 
T4.[RevisionNum] as RptLabelsRevisionNum, T4.[Rpt1TotalDedTax] as 
RptLabelsRpt1TotalDedTax, T4.[Rpt1TotalSATax] as RptLabelsRpt1TotalSATax, 
T4.[Rpt1TotalTax] as RptLabelsRpt1TotalTax, T4.[Rpt2TotalDedTax] as 
RptLabelsRpt2TotalDedTax, T4.[Rpt2TotalSATax] as RptLabelsRpt2TotalSATax, 
T4.[Rpt2TotalTax] as RptLabelsRpt2TotalTax, T4.[Rpt3TotalDedTax] as 
RptLabelsRpt3TotalDedTax, T4.[Rpt3TotalSATax] as RptLabelsRpt3TotalSATax, 
T4.[Rpt3TotalTax] as RptLabelsRpt3TotalTax, T4.[SubPartNum] as 
RptLabelsSubPartNum, T4.[SubPartOpts] as RptLabelsSubPartOpts, T4. 
[SubPartType] as RptLabelsSubPartType, T4.[Taxable] as RptLabelsTaxable, 
T4.[TaxCatID] as RptLabelsTaxCatID, T4.[UOM] as RptLabelsUOM, T4. 
[VendorPartOpts] as RptLabelsVendorPartOpts, T4.[VenPartNum] as 
RptLabelsVenPartNum, T4.[Calc_CostPer] as RptLabelsCalc_CostPer, T4. 
[Calc_DispUnitCost] as RptLabelsCalc_DispUnitCost, T4.[Calc_DtLineDesc] as 
RptLabelsCalc_DtLineDesc, T4.[Calc_ExtCost] as RptLabelsCalc_ExtCost, T4. 
[Calc_InTaxAmt] as RptLabelsCalc_InTaxAmt, T4.[Calc_LastLin] as 
RptLabelsCalc_LastLin, T4.[Calc_MfgID] as RptLabelsCalc_MfgID, T4. 
[Calc_OurUM] as RptLabelsCalc_OurUM, T4.[Calc_OurUM_UOMSymbol] as 
RptLabelsCalc_OurUM_UOMSymbol, T4.[Calc_PartUDChr1] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDChr1, T4.[Calc_PartUDChr2] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDChr2, T4.[Calc_PartUDChr3] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDChr3, T4.[Calc_PartUDChr4] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDChr4, T4.[Calc_PartUDDat1] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDat1, T4.[Calc_PartUDDat2] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDat2, T4.[Calc_PartUDDat3] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDat3, T4.[Calc_PartUDDat4] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDat4, T4.[Calc_PartUDDec1] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDec1, T4.[Calc_PartUDDec2] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDec2, T4.[Calc_PartUDDec3] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDec3, T4.[Calc_PartUDDec4] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDDec4, 
T4.[Calc_PartUDInt1] as RptLabelsCalc_PartUDInt1, T4.[Calc_PartUDInt2] as 
RptLabelsCalc_PartUDInt2, T4.[Calc_UnitCost] as RptLabelsCalc_UnitCost, 
T4.[Calc_UOMDescription] as RptLabelsCalc_UOMDescription, T4.[UOMSymbol] 
as RptLabelsUOMSymbol, T4.[AssemblySeq] as RptLabelsAssemblySeq, T4. 
[DropShip] as RptLabelsDropShip, T4.[EpicorFSA] as RptLabelsEpicorFSA, T4. 
[JobNum] as RptLabelsJobNum, T4.[JobSeq] as RptLabelsJobSeq, T4. 
[JobSeqType] as RptLabelsJobSeqType, T4.[OpenRelease] as 
RptLabelsOpenRelease, T4.[OrderRelNum] as RptLabelsOrderRelNum, T4. 
[ProjectID] as RptLabelsProjectID, T4.[RelQty] as RptLabelsRelQty, T4. 
[Status] as RptLabelsStatus, T4.[TaxExempt] as RptLabelsTaxExempt, T4. 
[TranType] as RptLabelsTranType, T4.[Calc_ManPartNum] as 
RptLabelsCalc_ManPartNum, T4.[Calc_Manufacturer] as 
RptLabelsCalc_Manufacturer, T4.[Calc_ShipToConName] as 
RptLabelsCalc_ShipToConName, T4.[Calc_SortDueDte] as 
RptLabelsCalc_SortDueDte, T4.[Description] as RptLabelsDescription, T4. 
[DocInInvoiceAmt] as RptLabelsDocInInvoiceAmt, T4.[DocInMiscAmt] as 
RptLabelsDocInMiscAmt, T4.[DocMiscAmt] as RptLabelsDocMiscAmt, T4. 
[MiscCode] as RptLabelsMiscCode, T4.[Percentage] as RptLabelsPercentage, 
T4.[Type] as RptLabelsType, T4.[MiscAmt] as RptLabelsMiscAmt, T4. 
[Calc_MiscSeq] as RptLabelsCalc_MiscSeq, T4.[DocTaxableAmt] as 
RptLabelsDocTaxableAmt, T4.[DocTaxAmt] as RptLabelsDocTaxAmt, T4.[Percent] 
as RptLabelsPercent, T4.[TaxCode] as RptLabelsTaxCode, T4.[MfgNum] as 
RptLabelsMfgNum, T4.[VendorNum] as RptLabelsVendorNum, T4.[VendPartNum] as 
RptLabelsVendPartNum, T4.[Calc_POLine] as RptLabelsCalc_POLine, T4. 
[Calc_PONum] as RptLabelsCalc_PONum, T4.[ExternalMESLastSync] as 
RptLabelsExternalMESLastSync, T4.[ExternalMESSyncRequired] as 
RptLabelsExternalMESSyncRequired, T4.[PartDescription] as 
RptLabelsPartDescription, T4.[PersonID] as RptLabelsPersonID, T3. 
[DropShip], T3.[EpicorFSA], T3.[JobSeqType], T3.[OpenRelease], T3. 
[OrderRelNum], T3.[RelQty], T3.[Status], T3.[TaxExempt], T3.[Date11], T3. 
[Date12], T3.[Date13], T3.[Number10], T3.[Number12], T3.[Number13], T3. 
[Number14], T3.[Number15], T3.[ShortChar10], T3.[Calc_ManPartNum], T3. 
[Calc_Manufacturer], T3.[Calc_ShipToConName], T3.[Calc_SortDueDte], T5. 
[ExternalMESLastSync], T5.[ExternalMESSyncRequired], T5.[PartDescription], 
T6.[DocTaxableAmt], T6.[DocTaxAmt], T6.[Percent], T6.[TaxCode], T7. 
[Description], T7.[DocMiscAmt], T7.[MiscAmt], T7.[Calc_MiscSeq], T8. 
[DocInInvoiceAmt], T8.[DocInMiscAmt], T8.[MiscCode], T8.[Percentage], T8. 
[Type], T9.[MfgNum], T9.[Calc_POLine], T9.[Calc_PONum], T10.[VendorNum], 
T10.[VendPartNum]
 FROM POHeader_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN PODetail_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T2
      ON T1.Company = T2.Company AND T1.PONum = T2.PONUM
      LEFT OUTER JOIN RptLabels_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T4
      ON T1.RptLanguageID = T4.RptLanguageID LEFT OUTER JOIN PORel_" + 
Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T3
      ON T3.Company = T2.Company AND T3.PONum = T2.PONUM
 AND T3.POLine = T2.POLine  LEFT OUTER JOIN JobHead_" + 
Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T5
      ON T5.Company = T3.Company AND T5.JobNum = T3.JobNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN POHeaderTax_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T6 ON  T1. 
[Company] = T6.[Company] AND T1.[PONum] = T6.[PONum]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORMisc_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T7 ON  T1. 
[Company] = T7.[Company] AND T1.[PONum] = T7.[PONum]
LEFT OUTER JOIN POMisc_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T8 ON  T1. 
[Company] = T8.[Company] AND T1.[PONum] = T8.[PONum]
LEFT OUTER JOIN PartXRefMfg_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T9 ON  T2. 
[Company] = T9.[Company] AND T2.[PONUM] = T9.[Calc_PONum] AND T2.[POLine] 
= 
T9.[Calc_POLine]
LEFT OUTER JOIN PartXRefVend_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + " T10 ON  
T2.[Company] = T10.[Company] AND T2.[PONUM] = T10.[Calc_PONum] AND T2. 
[POLine] = T10.[Calc_POLine]

 INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
   T1.PONum,
   T5.PersonID,
   T5.JobNum
from T1
inner join T2 on 
T1.Company = T2.Company
and T1.PONum = T2.PONUM
inner join T3 on 
T2.Company = T3.Company
and T2.PONUM = T3.PONum
and T2.POLine = T3.POLine
inner join T5 on 
T3.Company = T5.Company
and T3.JobNum = T5.JobNum)  as PlannerID
right outer join T1 as POHeader1 on 
POHeader1.PONum = PlannerID.T1.PONum"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset at the moment is just a string.
Take the equals sign and the start and end quotes out.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. This guy is not putting the query in as a dataset, he's attempting to add the subquery as an expression in a textbox.

Comment: Hi @Steve-o169 You are right. I am attempting to add subquery as an expression which I think is not possible. I am wrong in my approach. I have added the subquery inside the main dataset file as an INNER JOIN so that the PersonID can be returned by the SELECT statement in the PersonID field. 

I have added the whole SQL in my post. would be a great help if I can get some suggestions.The lower part contains the subquery

Currently, the PersonID field does not return any value. Even after I have added the subquery in the SQL, it does not show any value, I have possibly made some mistake.

Comment: Hi @Alan Schofield
I am trying to get the PersonID from a subquery that I have added now with the main SQL. I have added the whole SQL code in my post. 
In the SELECT statement, I have called PlannerID.T5.PersonID from the subquery from where I have got the. The subquery is at the end part of SQL. 

I think I have made some mistakes in calling the subquery returned PersonID value in the main SELECT statement.

Would be a great help if I can get some suggestions! Thanks a lot

Comment: If you do have this query in a dataset, then Alan's solution is correct, you'll need to remove the equals sign for this to work as a dataset. Something to make your subquery easier - declare aliases for the columns you're selecting so `T5.PersonID AS PersonID`. Maybe doesn't solve everything but simplifies things. I would also try an `OUTER APPLY` for the subquery rather than an inner join, as well. You also won't need quotes around the query in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve-o169. I am now trying your valuable suggestions. Let's see how it goes. I am not an expert but trying to understand how the SSRS works.